# Как написать условие для кнопки, если клик происходит быстрее, чем через секунду от предыдущего, кнопка блокируется (disabled), счетчик обнуляется

Tags: javascript

Сделайте кнопку, отображающую количество кликов по ней. Если очередной клик происходит быстрее,  чем через секунду от предыдущего клика по кнопке, то кнопка блокируется (используйте атрибут `disabled`), счетчик кликов обнуляется.

```js
const counter = document.getElementsByClassName ('counter') [0];
const button = document.getElementsByClassName('button')[0];
let clickCounter = 0;

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    clickCounter++;
    counter.textContent = 'Сделано кликов:' + clickCounter;
});
```

```html
<div class = "box">
    <h1 class="counter">Сделано кликов: 0  </h1>
    <button class="button">Нажми на меня!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: блокируется на совсем? или тоже есть таймаут для этого?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте setTimeout, который будет отсчитывать время на 1 секунду после нажатия и флаг, по которому проверять

```js
const counter = document.getElementsByClassName ('counter') [0];
const button = document.getElementsByClassName('button')[0];

let clickCounter = 0;
let timeOff = false 

button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if (timeOff) {
        clickCounter = 0;
        e.target.disabled = true;
    } else {
        timeOff = true;
        clickCounter++;
        setTimeout(() => {
            timeOff = false;
            e.target.disabled = false;
        }, 1000);
    }
    counter.textContent = 'Сделано кликов:' + clickCounter;
});
```

```html
<div class = "box">
<h1 class="counter">Сделано кликов: 0  </h1>
<button class="button">Нажми на меня!</button>
</div>
```