# Как сделать срабатывание скрипта через раз при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как сделать, что-бы при нажатии на кнопку скрипт срабатывал через раз?

```js
document.getElementById('yourId').onclick = function() {
    alert('Неверный код');
}
```

```html
<button id="yourId"><span>Подтвердить код</span></button>
```

Comment: Добавьте флаг `let flg = true;` и проверяйте, если **true** выполняем иначе ничего не делаем. При каждом тыке меняем `flg = !flg`

Comment: Вот тут похожая реализация [реагирования кнопки по условию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1475865/1475870#1475870). Только там таймер, а вам нужно условие клика.

Comment: Не стоит засорять пространство, лучше через установку значения в data-flag элемента

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать подобное просто через внешнюю переменную:

```js
let oddFlag = true

function oddHandler(){
  if (oddFlag) alert('Неверный код')
  oddFlag = !oddFlag
}

document.getElementById('yourId').onclick = oddHandler
```

```html
<button id="yourId"><span>Подтвердить код</span></button>
```

Но вообще, есть решение поэлегантнее - через замыкание. Но, в таком случае нужно присвоить ВЫЗОВ функции:

```js
function createOddHandler(){
  let oddFlag = true
    
  return () => {
    if (oddFlag) alert('Неверный код')
    oddFlag = !oddFlag
  }
}

document.getElementById('yourId').onclick = createOddHandler()
```

```html
<button id="yourId"><span>Подтвердить код</span></button>
```